# Set Symfony Request attribute in Request Listener

Tags: symfony

I have a Symfony event listener which is listening on "kernel.request".  I would like to add an attribute to the request which I can access in my controllers.  I tried doing this:

```
$request = $event->getRequest();
$request->attributes->set('test', 'testvalue');
```

However, the "test" attribute is not a part of the request object in my controllers.  I am not receiving any errors, but it's just not there.  What else do I need to do?

edit:

I verified that the listener is being called.  In my controller, I have this, but don't get the "test" attribute:

```
class DefaultController extends BaseController
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($request->attributes); echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

Comment: What you posted should work.  Verify your listener is actually being called.  And that the controller is using get or the action has an argument called $test.

Comment: Which Symfony version? 2.4+?

Comment: Cerad: what I think that Steven is trying to do is to inject arbitrary arguments into the response.

Comment: just updated my question with more details

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my Event Listener was returning before my attribute was being set.  Stupid mistake.